# Words preceding a direct question (in general and specifically in BrE)

Tags: grammaticality

Are such words unacceptable? We can't say:

*Tell me, what time is it now?*
**or**
*I forgot, how long will your trip last?*

can we?

Or are the following affimative sentences with indirect questions the only possibility?

*Tell me what time it is now.

I forgot how long your trip will last.*

As I learnt from the answer and comments, such questions are pretty acceptable in AmE. *So the question is if they are also suitable for British English.*

Comment: @KannE: thank you for the examples! They are very useful, but is that used in British English (a question to all who know as well)?

Comment: Why would these sentences be unacceptable? Are you questioning the use of the punctuation? People say things like this all the time. The punctuation used to represent the speech is stylistic. If I were worried about the punctuation, I would probably use a dash or turn it into two separate sentences. But there's nothing *wrong* with the comma (or the words).

Comment: @JasonBassford: no, I'm worried not about punctuation, but thank you for your suggestions. *Why would these sentences be unacceptable?* When I google searched on the direct questions, I didn't find such examples. That's why I concluded that they might be unacceptable.

Comment: Expressions such as "_tell me_" or "_I forgot_" used to initiate a discussion or introduce a question are extremely common in BrE. They are a type of _discourse marker_ such as "_well_", or "_you know_": https://www.thoughtco.com/discourse-marker-or-dm-1690463 .

Comment: Really? Thanks then! But the site doesn't seem British though.

Comment: I am a British English native speaker as well as a teacher of English for over 35 years. You can trust me that such expressions are common in everyday conversation in Britain. (A nice _argumentum ab auctoritate_!)

Comment: @Shoe: that's great! Thank you very much then!! It sounds really convincing!

Comment: *A nice argumentum ab auctoritate!* Yes, indeed! :)

Comment: In the UK, far from their being the only possibilities "Tell me what time it is now" sounds quite rude in isolation and "I forgot how long your trip will last" is a statement rather than a question. I would expect the second one to be followed by a direct question such as "How long is it going to be?". Your examples with the introduction separated from the question by a comma is much more common and acceptable.

Comment: @BoldBen, thanks a lot! That really helps to understand it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe their use is unacceptable. It looks as if you are writing down what someone said. I cannot imagine how they could be considered wrong.

Comment: Thank you, Elliot! So does it mean that in speech it's used without doubt?

Comment: The only way to find out is to use it and see the reaction. I would not stop to ask what was meant if you were to use these in speech.

Comment: Well, but you can also not stop me if I make some mistake, at least out of politeness. But that doesn't mean that everything is all right. :)

Comment: Language like everything else is a social process. We look inward to what we know and are comfortable while exploring outward to what is unknown and has yet to be mastered. Polite interaction is the means to achieve this.